# Move variable to one side of the equation

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Say if I have a formula like so:

```
a1*a2*a3^(a4 + 1)*(1 - E^(a5*a6/a3^a4/a2)) == 0
```

How do I move a3 to the right? I've tried to follow other examples here on stack exchange but couldn't find anything that worked on this kind of formula.

Using Solve[] causes this error:

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available
>   to Solve.

Comment: You've seen `Solve[]`?

Comment: Yes but I get this error: "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve."

Comment: @Zammbi Start a fresh  mathematica kernel (ie. close the Mma app and start it again)

Comment: @belisarius I tried that but still same error. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Zammbi post your Solve[] code, and the Mathematica version you are using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean by *move `a3` to the right* that you want to solve for `a3`. Are you working in real numbers, then `Reduce` might be a better option than `Solve`

```
Reduce[a1*a2*a3^(a4 + 1)*(1 - E^(a5*a6/a3^a4/a2)) == 0, a3, Reals]
```

and you get

> ```
> (-1 < a4 < 0 && a3 == 0) || (C[1] \[Element] Integers && (
> (a1 == 0 && a4 == -C[1] && a3 < 0) || (a2 == 0 && 
> a4 == -C[1] && a3 < 0) || (a5 == 0 && a4 == -C[1] && 
> a3 < 0) || (a6 == 0 && a4 == -C[1] && a3 < 0))) || (a1 == 0 && 
> a3 > 0) || (a2 == 0 && a3 > 0) || (a5 == 0 && a3 > 0) || (a6 == 0 && a3 > 0)
> ```

Now you have to understand the solution. Look at the structure of your equation. It's a product and therefore it is zero when either factor is zero. All the possibilities given (as logical formula) tell you how it is possible to make one factor zero. For instance setting `a3==0` but this holds only, if the exponent containing `a4` fulfills some requirements, namely `-1 < a4 < 0`.

If you are really only interested in the solution that contains `a3`, you can use `Solve` which gives you effectively only the first part of the solution of `Reduce`

```
Solve[a1*a2*a3^(a4 + 1)*(1 - E^(a5*a6/a3^a4/a2)) == 0, a3, Reals]
```

> ```
> Out[4]= {{a3 -> ConditionalExpression[0, -1 < a4 < 0]}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Goes over my head. So probably will leave out this programming optimisation I was trying to do.

Comment: It is interesting to understand, why without specification of the domain Solve returns no solution, while with the domain it does?

Comment: Exponentiation in the complex domain is much harder with different rules. Without specification of the domain, Mathematica assumes the complex domain.